# Angular Material Table doesn't display fetched data from local server

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material

I can't display data from local server.

The client does request, server takes data from a csv file. The data will be sent as json. I try to parse within MatTableDataSource data and display it into the table.

It looks like, the table has no data but you can see the data in the logs.

**File with typescript code**

personal-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../core/api.service';

import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

export interface PersonalList {
  Name: string;
  Position: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personal-list',
  templateUrl: './personal-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personal-list.component.css']
})
export class PersonalListComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'position'];
  dataSource;
  person;

  personal: PersonalList[];
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiService.getPersonalList().subscribe((data: PersonalList[]) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      console.log(this.dataSource);
    });
    console.log(this.dataSource);
  }

}
```

**File with HTML Code**
personal-list.component.html

```
<p>personal-list works!</p>

<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Position</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

[Screenshot with the table and console outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg1JB.png)

Comment: Maybe your data arrives after the table has been rendered and for any reason it is not updated.

Comment: Is there any refresh function? Can I try to update the data force?

Comment: I thought that the rendering function will wait for the fetching function in `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data hasn't been sent right from server.

I changed 
`data = pandas.read_csv('./Data/personal.csv').loc[:, ['Name', 'Position']].to_json()`

to

`data = pandas.read_csv('./Data/personal.csv').loc[:, ['Name', 'Position']].to_json(orient='records')`

The method `to_json` takes orient 'columns' as default.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html